# node.js createReadStream hangs process.exit() when exit events are listened

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to read input device events from /dev/input/by-id/ on linux. I tried using input-event npm package in my project but it was hanging my entire terminal when I tried stopping it with CTRL+C and kill -9 was needed. I thought it's the packages fault, but it turns out it's actually a problem with me having listeners on the SIG signals:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() { exitHandler('SIGINT'); });
process.on('SIGUSR1', function() { exitHandler('SIGUSR1'); });
process.on('SIGUSR2', function() { exitHandler('SIGUSR2'); });
process.on('SIGTERM', function() { exitHandler('SIGTERM'); });
```

When I remove the listeners, it starts working properly (can CTRL+C out of node). If I keep the listeners, but remove the readStreams, it also works. I tried closing the stream & file descriptor before process.exit(), but it doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let monitoredDevices = { 
    devices: [],

    addDevice: function(path) {

        fs.open(path, 'r', (e, fd) => {
            if(e)
                return;
            let dev = { path: path, fd: null, stream: null};
            dev.fd = fd;
            // comment out the stream and it process can exit normally
            dev.stream = fs.createReadStream(null, { fd: dev.fd, mode: 'r'});
            let ix = this.devices.push(dev);

            if(dev.stream) {
                dev.stream.on('data', (data) => {
                    console.log('DATA('+dev.path+'):', data);
                });

                dev.stream.on('error', (e) => {
                    if(e.code == 'ENODEV') {
                        // disconnected
                        this.devices.splice(ix, 1);
                        fs.closeSync(dev.fd);
                        dev.stream.close();
                        delete dev;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    },

    hasDevice: function(path) {
        return this.devices.find(x => x.path == path) ? true : false;
    }
};

setInterval(function() {
    // Query /dev/input/by-id/ for new connected devices and open readstream on new ones
    fs.readdir('/dev/input/by-id', (err, files) => {
        if(err)
            return;
        files.forEach(file => {
            if(fs.lstatSync('/dev/input/by-id/'+file).isDirectory())
                return;
            if(monitoredDevices.hasDevice('/dev/input/by-id/'+file))
                return;
            monitoredDevices.addDevice('/dev/input/by-id/'+file);
            console.log('EVENT:', file);
        });
    });
}, 500);


let _shutdownInProcess = false;
function exitHandler(signal='') {
    if(!_shutdownInProcess) {
        _shutdownInProcess = true;
        for(let i = 0; i < monitoredDevices.devices.length; i++) {
            console.log('Closing ' + monitoredDevices.devices[i].path + ' (' + monitoredDevices.devices[i].fd +')', fs.closeSync(monitoredDevices.devices[i].fd));
            monitoredDevices.devices[i].stream.close();
        }
        console.log('\033[31m Caught exit signal ' + signal + ', closing... \x1b[0m');
        process.exit();
    }
}

// Comment out the events and the process exist properly
process.on('SIGINT', function() { exitHandler('SIGINT'); });
process.on('SIGUSR1', function() { exitHandler('SIGUSR1'); });
process.on('SIGUSR2', function() { exitHandler('SIGUSR2'); });
process.on('SIGTERM', function() { exitHandler('SIGTERM'); });
```

This obviously needs root privileges to be able to read the input events.
When I CTRL+C (or execute `killall node`) the exitHandler is getting fired, but it stops right after the red console log and I cannot do anything anymore in that terminal. Only `killall -9 node` works.

I found a similar issue here: [Node.js process.exit() will not exit with a createReadStream open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853218/node-js-process-exit-will-not-exit-with-a-createreadstream-open)

But it doesn't really solve the problem, only forces some abnormal termination of the process. Is there any way to force the streams to close before exiting? I unfortunately need to have these signal listeners as I'm using them to do other stuff before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a bug inside node.js core that exists since the beginning and it's not planned to be fixed (there is a warning about it on Readline docs). So I went with using a simple `cat` child process and using it's stdout instead of creating my own stream, works like a charm but instead of checking the stream itself for ENODEV error, you need to check process exit as cat just exists when device ceases to exist.

```
dev.proc = require('child_process').spawn('cat', [path]);
dev.stream = dev.proc.stdout;
```

Comment: See here for more detailed information: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15439